# Duplicate Content - 301 Redirect Section of Joomla Website Using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website with a forum and I am trying to clean up duplicate content issues.

What I am trying to do is 301 redirect any URLS with mywebsite.com/recent-topics/category-title/post-title.html to mywebsite.com/forum/category-title/post-title.html.

It is a Joomla website and a htaccess file is already in use. I have added this string to the end of the htaccess file but it's not working:

```
RewriteRule ^/recent-topics/(.*) /forum [R=301,L]
```

Full htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

#RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/component/) [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.

RewriteRule ^/recent-topics/(.*) /forum [R=301,L]
```

Can anyone offer any advice as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your rule just under the `RewriteEngine On`. The redirects need to happen *before* any type of routing happens. The Joomla rules do routing so your rule that redirects to `/forum` will never get applied.